# Canvas fill shape with text

Tags: javascript

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m3LLqtq8/) example in canvas. I would like to know how I can add text in shapes.

I have looked into the code that draws shapes but not really sure how to add text. I was able to add text but it doesn't move with balls?

```
function draw()
            {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight);
                var i = balls.length;
                while(--i > -1)
                {
                    context.fillStyle = balls[i].color;
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(balls[i].x,balls[i].y,balls[i].size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fill();
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean add text in shapes? You want a line of text follow the ball?

Comment: @fuyushimoya means shapes/circles should contain text eg: ball1, ball2 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the ball's x and y value to make sure the text follow the ball, and use `textAlign` and `textBaseline` to easily align the text.

```
function draw()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight);
    // Align once an for all.
    context.textAlign = 'center'; // Set text align to center.
    context.textBaseline = 'middle'; // Set text vertical align to middle.
    var i = balls.length;
    while(--i > -1)
    {
        context.fillStyle = balls[i].color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(balls[i].x,balls[i].y,balls[i].size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        // Easier to see the text.
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        // Draw text `Ball # i` centered at position (x, y),
        // with the width of the text equal to ball's size * 2.
        context.fillText('Ball #' + i, balls[i].x ,balls[i].y, balls[i].size * 2);
    }
}
```

See altered [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3LLqtq8/5/), is that what you want?

P.S : When playing with canvas, it's always best to keep [HTML5 Canvas Cheat Sheet](https://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html) handy.

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Is there any easy trick to center text and size them accordingly?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer, check the jsfiddle to see  how they can align to the center.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering if there is any way to make balls rotate randomly. As text is always straight? Just let me know if you have an idea. I can dig myself deeper just need a pointer. Thanks again

Comment: You may use `context.save` before drawing each ball, `context.translate` to move the ball to origin, `context.rotate` to rotate the ball, then use another `context.translate` to move the ball back to its origin position, and call `context.restore` to restore all transformation you did to init status.

Comment: I've alter again the __[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3LLqtq8/7/)__ and add a random rotate value at ball generate function, you can see how to apply the rotatation on each ball.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Appreciate it !